# imshow() subplots generate unwanted white spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, whitespace, imshow

When plotting two (or more) subplots, there is a large areas of white spaces within the plots (on all four sides) as seen here:
[image]

Following is the code which I used to plot it.

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for kk in range(57,58):
    fn_i=str(kk)
    image_file_1='RedshiftOutput00'+fn_i+'_Slice_z_RadioPowerDSA.png'
    image_file_2='RedshiftOutput00'+fn_i+'_Slice_z_RadioPowerTRA.png'
    image_file_3='RedshiftOutput00'+fn_i+'_Slice_z_RadioPowerDSA+TRA.png'

    image_1 = plt.imread(image_file_1)
    image_2 = plt.imread(image_file_2)
    image_3 = plt.imread(image_file_3)      

    ax1 = subplot(131)
    plt.imshow(image_1)
    plt.axis('off')  # clear x- and y-axes

    ax2 = subplot(132)
    plt.imshow(image_2)
    plt.axis('off')  # clear x- and y-axes

    ax3 = subplot(133)
    plt.imshow(image_3)
    plt.axis('off')  # clear x- and y-axes

    plt.savefig('RedshiftOutput00'+fn_i+'_all.png')
```

I am also uploading the 3 images used in this code to making the code a Minimal Working Example

1) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6l5iRWTUbHWSTF2R3E1THBGeVk/view?usp=sharing

2) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6l5iRWTUbHWaFI4dHAzcWpiOEU/view?usp=sharing

3) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6l5iRWTUbHWaG8xclFlcGJNaUk/view?usp=sharing

How we can remove this white space ? I tried by fixing the whole plot size, still white space is comming.

Comment: try `plt.tight_layout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mel's comment above (use `plt.tight_layout()`) works in many situations, but sometimes you need a little more control. To manipulate axes more finely (useful, e.g., when you have lots of colorbars or `twin`-ned axes), you can use `plt.subplots_adjust()` or a `GridSpec` object.

`GridSpec` objects allow you to specify the horizontal and vertical extents of individual axes, as well as their proportional width and height & spacing. `subplots_adjust()` moves your axes around after you've already plotted stuff on them. I prefer using the first option, but both are [documented](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) [well](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_adjust.html).

It also may help to fool around with the size of your figure. If you have lots of whitespace width-wise, make the width of the figure smaller.

Here's some example code that I used to set up a recent plot:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(
        nrows=1, ncols=3, left=0.1, bottom=0.25, right=0.95, top=0.95,
        wspace=0.05, hspace=0., width_ratios=[1, 1, 1])
NII_ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
SII_ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
OI_ax = plt.subplot(gs[2])
```

And the result:

[image: GridSpec result]

Then, if you need a colorbar, adjust the `right` argument in `GridSpec` to something like 0.85, and use `fig.add_axes()` with a list `[left_lim, bottom, width, height]` and use that as the axis argument for a `fig.colorbar()`

Comment: With gridspec.GridSpec the problem has been solved... :-)